# Dataflow Display Data missing from composite transform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I'm trying the new [display data](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/java-sdk/JavaDoc/com/google/cloud/dataflow/sdk/transforms/display/DisplayData#class-displaydata) functionality in Dataflow to make additional details show up in the Google Cloud Dataflow UI. However, the display data for custom `PTransform`'s doesn't show up. In my Dataflow pipeline, I have a transform like:

```java
Pipeline p = // ..
p.apply(new PTransform<PCollection<Integer>, PCollection<Integer>>() {
  @Override
  public PCollection<Integer> apply(PCollection<Integer> input) {
    return input
      .apply(/* .. */)
      .apply(/* .. */)
      .apply(/* .. */);
  }

  @Override
  public void populateDisplayData(DisplayData.Builder builder) {
    builder.add(DisplayData.item("foo", "bar"));
  }
});
```

When I run the Dataflow job, the UI doesn't seem to show the `foo=bar` display data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Display data is not supported on [composite transforms](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/model/composite-transforms). Instead, you can attach display data to any user-defined function which your transform executes. For example, if one of the inner transforms in the above composite uses a `ParDo`, you could re-write the display data methods as:

```java
Pipeline p = // ..
p.apply(new PTransform<PCollection<Integer>, PCollection<Integer>>() {
  @Override
  public PCollection<Integer> apply(PCollection<Integer> input) {
    return input
      .apply(/* .. */)
      .apply(/* .. */)
      .apply(ParDo.of(new DoFn<Integer, Integer>() {
        @Override
        public void processElement(ProcessContext c) { /* .. */ } 

        @Override
        public void populateDisplayData(DisplayData.Builder builder) {
          builder.add(DisplayData.item("foo", "bar"));
        }            
      }));
  }
});
```

There is [a JIRA issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-366) to extend display data functionality to composite transforms in Beam and Dataflow SDKs.